# How to interpret 肉麻

Tags: word-requests

Dictionaries define 肉麻 as *nauseating; sickening; disgusting*. But I don't think those are accurate because those words are showing disproval while 肉麻 could show approval depending on how you use it. The word is being used when somebody says something overly sweet. E.g.

> A: 我太喜欢你了！ 我愿意天天和你在一起！
>
> B: 好肉麻啊。

This might be a question for the ELL site. But I don't know how to describe the word precisely in English, so I might just ask here. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I can not, however, provide with a good answer. But here is my humble opinion, when saying 肉麻，most likely the person is feeling shy or even shame either for himself or herself, or someone he or she is referring to.

Comment: bkrs：fruity, mawkish  (2) [dally with]∶轻佻地狎昵
和情人肉麻了一阵 
iciba：伟大的激情和肉麻的温情之间的分界线究竟在哪里, 我无法确定. mawkish

Answer (score 2):

Consider: **gushy**.

Google defines it as:

> gushy
>   /ˈɡʌʃi/
>   adjective
>   excessively effusive.

and gives the example:

> "her gushy manner"

---

[91dub](https://www.91dub.com/search/Especially%20when%20they%20started%20being%20all%20gushy.?type=search) also has the show《牛仔裤的夏天》subtitled with the sentence:

> Especially when they started being all gushy.
>   尤其是在很肉麻的时候.

Answer (score 2):

Cheesy,前几天在一个英文广播上听到的。广播里的外国主播对于cheesy使用场景的描述是:we often use it to talk about overly sentimental songs,movies or people who sing those songs or acting those movies.

Answer (score 1):

In the given context, I'd plump for:

B: Errrh! Gross!

but this will never "show approval."

Maybe, if no disapproval is intended, which I assumed:

B: You're making me blush!

Comment: 'gross' shows too much disapproval there. 肉麻 in this context could show approval. B could actually pretty enjoy those words said by A, though he/she said 肉麻 in order to hide his/her enjoyment from other spectators nearby.